# Django - DoesNotExist

Tags: django

**UPDATE**

After adding the try/except block,...

```
if user_membership.stripe_customer_id is None or user_membership.stripe_customer_id == '':
    new_customer_id = stripe.Customer.create(email=instance.email)
    try:
        membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
    except Membership.DoesNotExist:
        user_membership.stripe_customer_id = new_customer_id['id']
        user_membership.membership = free_membership
        user_membership.save()
```

...I get the following error:

Traceback:

```
File "/home/AndrewsBRN/django_todo_app/memberships/models.py" in post_save_usermembership_create
  48.             membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  408.                 self.model._meta.object_name

During handling of the above exception (Membership matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py" in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
  76.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  137.         return super(LoginView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in dispatch
  80.                                             **kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  97.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in post
  103.             response = self.form_valid(form)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/views.py" in form_valid
  150.             return form.login(self.request, redirect_url=success_url)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/forms.py" in login
  197.                             redirect_url=redirect_url)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/utils.py" in perform_login
  150.         adapter.login(request, user)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/allauth/account/adapter.py" in login
  391.         django_login(request, user)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py" in login
  132.     user_logged_in.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in update_last_login
  20.     user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py" in save
  66.         super().save(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  790.                 update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in send
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py" in <listcomp>
  175.             for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)

File "/home/AndrewsBRN/django_todo_app/memberships/models.py" in post_save_usermembership_create
  51.             user_membership.membership = free_membership

Exception Type: NameError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: name 'free_membership' is not defined
```

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

---

Everything worked fine in development. But after deployment, I get:

```
  File "/home/AndrewsBRN/django_todo_app/memberships/models.py", line 47, in post_save_usermembership_create
    free_membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
memberships.models.DoesNotExist: Membership matching query does not exist.
```

---

I tried to remove 'django.contrib.sites' as per another solution to this error here on SO, but that does not work.

---

memberships/models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from datetime import datetime
import stripe
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = (
    ('Enterprise', 'ent'),
    ('Professional', 'pro'),
    ('Free', 'free')
)
class Membership(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    membership_type = models.CharField(
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Free',
        max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    stripe_plan_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_type

class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(
        Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    member = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def post_save_usermembership_create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(
        user=instance)


    if user_membership.stripe_customer_id is None or user_membership.stripe_customer_id == '':
        new_customer_id = stripe.Customer.create(email=instance.email)
        free_membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
        user_membership.stripe_customer_id = new_customer_id['id']
        user_membership.membership = free_membership
        user_membership.save()


post_save.connect(post_save_usermembership_create,
                  sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

---

settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

SECRET_KEY = '***'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['***']
ROOT_URLCONF = 'videoservice.urls'
SESSION_ENGINE = 'qsessions.backends.cached_db'
LOGIN_REDIRECT = '/'
REGISTER_REDIRECT = '/'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

DEBUG = True

if DEBUG:
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = '***'
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = '***'

else:
    # live keys
    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = '***'
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = '***'

SITE_ID = 1

STAR_RATINGS_RERATE = False
STAR_RATINGS_ANONYMOUS = True

GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/paths/')

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'qsessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',

    'courses',
    'memberships',
    'star_ratings',
    'avatar',
    'home',
    'online_users'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'qsessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'online_users.middleware.OnlineNowMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myproject.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/AndrewsBRN/django_todo_app/static'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/AndrewsBRN/django_todo_app/media'
```

---

Also, all media files are gone.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

> memberships.models.DoesNotExist: Membership matching query does not exist.

it is because you have no object with this params:

> Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')

Good practice is to put this code in try...catch block

```
try:
   membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
catch Membership.DoesNotExist:
   membership = ....<create it or set None>...
```

Second question about Media handling on production - media files on production are handling using your views or using webserver static aliases - please read official manual about it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

UPDATE:
Use something like this:

```
if user_membership.stripe_customer_id is None or user_membership.stripe_customer_id == '':
    new_customer_id = stripe.Customer.create(email=instance.email)
    try:
        free_membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
    except except Membership.DoesNotExist:
        free_membership = None

    user_membership.stripe_customer_id = new_customer_id['id']
    user_membership.membership = free_membership
    user_membership.save()
```

Comment: OK, I changed catch to except and now I get a NameError at /accounts/login/
name 'free_membership' is not defined. 
I dont understand why this is happening. It worked perfectly fine in development. The membership types are defined

Comment: If I understood correctly^ it will by smthg like this:

Comment: `
    if user_membership.stripe_customer_id is None or user_membership.stripe_customer_id == '':
        new_customer_id = stripe.Customer.create(email=instance.email)
        try:
            free_membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
        except except Membership.DoesNotExist:
            free_membership = None
            
        user_membership.stripe_customer_id = new_customer_id['id']
        user_membership.membership = free_membership
        user_membership.save()`